# Logging in Apps, where, and what other options do I have

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin

If I am using a provider hosted app with the code below, its not clear to me how can I monitor logs, provider hosted apps runs in this case in a separate iis site, correct?

The System.Diagnostics line where does it log to?
ULS?
IIS Logs?
Event Logs?

I am trying to know a good approach to debugging apps once they are in production.
Specially if each app is different iis site

What other options do I have to the System.Diagnostics line?

```
EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver =
                            new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
                        receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;

                        //Get WCF URL where this message was handled
                        OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
                        Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;

                        receiver.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();

                        receiver.ReceiverName = RECEIVER_NAME;
                        receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;

                        //Add the new event receiver to a list in the host web
                        jobsList.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);

                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Added ItemAdded receiver at "
                                + msg.Headers.To.ToString());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In think this blog post has it all regarding this:  http://sharepoint-community.net/m/blogpost?id=6614983%3ABlogPost%3A66076

The basic idea is to use one of the many existing logging frameworks that are not SharePoint specific. Since a provider hosted app has no access to SharePoint logs, we have to create and use or own logs.

LogEntries seems like a good framework with many possibilities (have not tested it my self).

Your System.Diagnosics.Trace.Write will only output your logging to subscribed listeners (example being a debugging session in Visual Studio)

Comment: Link not working.

Comment: New link added!